# Movie about Tales of Rabbi Nachman

Tags: product-recommendation, performance-entertainment, breslov

I'm looking for the complete movie related to the trailer that is in this video: https://youtu.be/qnWAQdxDS-k . Do you know where I can buy a copy of this full movie?
Warning: I have already emailed Laadan International to two different addresses of this company and received no response.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Is the movie about Judaism (as opposed to about a Jew)? If it’s not then it might fall within the scope of this site.

Comment: Hi @alex, is a film about the tales of Rabbi Nachman, founder of the Breslov movement.  Certainly it is totally about Judaism, essentially Kaballa, prophecies and mitzvot.

Comment: @Alex We have plenty of questions on here that ask for product recommendation. As the product in question is certainly related to Judaism, it's in scope for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy it [here](https://www.rebbenachmanmovie.com/outside-israel-dvd) on their website. I cannot vouch for the reliability of this website.